# Would this be a correct redefinition of the method == and the value null?

Tags: scala

According to the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/12-the-scala-standard-library.html), we have

```
abstract class Any {
  ...
  final def == (that: Any): Boolean  =
      if (null eq this) null eq that else this equals that
  ...
}

abstract final class Null extends AnyRef
```

*My question* is whether the above is equivalent to the following reformulation:

```
abstract class Any {
  ...
  final def == = equals
  ...
}

case object null extends AnyRef {
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case that: AnyRef => null eq that
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Comment: `null.equals(null)` throws a `NullPointerException` and `null == null` evaluates to `true` in the original version, whereas in the reformulation, both `null.equals(null)` and `null == null` evaluate to `true`.

Comment: They aren't equivalent exactly for the case you just specified :)